# Monitoring PCI Express bus usage

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, nvidia, gpu-monitor

I am looking for a program that can monitor the PCI Express bus usage on Linux. I am mostly interested in the PCI Express bus usage between an Nvidia GPU and CPU.

---

I am aware of https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-optimize-data-transfers-cuda-cc/ , which gives a piece of code (`bandwidthtest.cu`) to measure the data transfer rate between the GPU and the CPU:

```
/* Copyright (c) 1993-2015, NVIDIA CORPORATION. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *  * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *  * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *  * Neither the name of NVIDIA CORPORATION nor the names of its
 *    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS ``AS IS'' AND ANY
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY
 * OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

// Convenience function for checking CUDA runtime API results
// can be wrapped around any runtime API call. No-op in release builds.
inline
cudaError_t checkCuda(cudaError_t result)
{
#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
  if (result != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "CUDA Runtime Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(result));
    assert(result == cudaSuccess);
  }
#endif
  return result;
}

void profileCopies(float        *h_a, 
                   float        *h_b, 
                   float        *d, 
                   unsigned int  n,
                   char         *desc)
{
  printf("\n%s transfers\n", desc);

  unsigned int bytes = n * sizeof(float);

  // events for timing
  cudaEvent_t startEvent, stopEvent; 

  checkCuda( cudaEventCreate(&startEvent) );
  checkCuda( cudaEventCreate(&stopEvent) );

  checkCuda( cudaEventRecord(startEvent, 0) );
  checkCuda( cudaMemcpy(d, h_a, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
  checkCuda( cudaEventRecord(stopEvent, 0) );
  checkCuda( cudaEventSynchronize(stopEvent) );

  float time;
  checkCuda( cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, startEvent, stopEvent) );
  printf("  Host to Device bandwidth (GB/s): %f\n", bytes * 1e-6 / time);

  checkCuda( cudaEventRecord(startEvent, 0) );
  checkCuda( cudaMemcpy(h_b, d, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
  checkCuda( cudaEventRecord(stopEvent, 0) );
  checkCuda( cudaEventSynchronize(stopEvent) );

  checkCuda( cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, startEvent, stopEvent) );
  printf("  Device to Host bandwidth (GB/s): %f\n", bytes * 1e-6 / time);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (h_a[i] != h_b[i]) {
      printf("*** %s transfers failed ***", desc);
      break;
    }
  }

  // clean up events
  checkCuda( cudaEventDestroy(startEvent) );
  checkCuda( cudaEventDestroy(stopEvent) );
}

int main()
{
  unsigned int nElements = 990*1024*1024;
  const unsigned int bytes = nElements * sizeof(float);

  // host arrays
  float *h_aPageable, *h_bPageable;   
  float *h_aPinned, *h_bPinned;

  // device array
  float *d_a;

  // allocate and initialize
  h_aPageable = (float*)malloc(bytes);                    // host pageable
  h_bPageable = (float*)malloc(bytes);                    // host pageable
  checkCuda( cudaMallocHost((void**)&h_aPinned, bytes) ); // host pinned
  checkCuda( cudaMallocHost((void**)&h_bPinned, bytes) ); // host pinned
  checkCuda( cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, bytes) );           // device

  for (int i = 0; i < nElements; ++i) h_aPageable[i] = i;      
  memcpy(h_aPinned, h_aPageable, bytes);
  memset(h_bPageable, 0, bytes);
  memset(h_bPinned, 0, bytes);

  // output device info and transfer size
  cudaDeviceProp prop;
  checkCuda( cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, 0) );

  printf("\nDevice: %s\n", prop.name);
  printf("Transfer size (MB): %d\n", bytes / (1024 * 1024));

  // perform copies and report bandwidth
  profileCopies(h_aPageable, h_bPageable, d_a, nElements, "Pageable");
  profileCopies(h_aPinned, h_bPinned, d_a, nElements, "Pinned");

  printf("\n");

  // cleanup
  cudaFree(d_a);
  cudaFreeHost(h_aPinned);
  cudaFreeHost(h_bPinned);
  free(h_aPageable);
  free(h_bPageable);

  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, the `bandwidthtest.cu` code can be obtained as follows:
    git clone https://github.com/parallel-forall/code-samples.git
    cd code-samples/series/cuda-cpp/optimize-data-transfers

which can be compiled using:

```
nvcc bandwidthtest.cu -o bandwidthtest
```

and run with:

```
nvprof ./bandwidthtest
```

The output is for example:

```
==20955== NVPROF is profiling process 20955, command: ./bandwidthtest

Device: GeForce GTX TITAN X
Transfer size (MB): 3960

Pageable transfers
  Host to Device bandwidth (GB/s): 3.073613
  Device to Host bandwidth (GB/s): 3.588289

Pinned transfers
  Host to Device bandwidth (GB/s): 12.004806
  Device to Host bandwidth (GB/s): 12.929138

==20955== Profiling application: ./bandwidthtest
==20955== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 53.45%  1.69626s         2  848.13ms  345.81ms  1.35045s  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
 46.55%  1.47753s         2  738.76ms  321.07ms  1.15646s  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]

==20955== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 46.63%  4.10457s         2  2.05229s  1.92812s  2.17646s  cudaMallocHost
 36.07%  3.17518s         4  793.80ms  321.13ms  1.35099s  cudaMemcpy
 17.21%  1.51471s         2  757.36ms  706.92ms  807.79ms  cudaFreeHost
  0.03%  2.7035ms       332  8.1430us     150ns  343.79us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
  0.03%  2.2626ms         1  2.2626ms  2.2626ms  2.2626ms  cudaMalloc
  0.01%  909.22us         1  909.22us  909.22us  909.22us  cudaFree
  0.01%  857.27us         1  857.27us  857.27us  857.27us  cudaGetDeviceProperties
  0.00%  232.82us         4  58.206us  54.305us  60.715us  cuDeviceTotalMem
  0.00%  193.19us         4  48.298us  45.287us  51.158us  cuDeviceGetName
  0.00%  115.60us         8  14.450us  2.3390us  28.703us  cudaEventRecord
  0.00%  71.927us         4  17.981us  3.1920us  61.514us  cudaEventSynchronize
  0.00%  31.314us         4  7.8280us     709ns  22.528us  cudaEventCreate
  0.00%  25.850us         4  6.4620us     710ns  12.378us  cudaEventDestroy
  0.00%  10.234us         4  2.5580us  2.1590us  3.1230us  cudaEventElapsedTime
  0.00%  2.2380us         2  1.1190us     261ns  1.9770us  cuDeviceGetCount
  0.00%  1.5190us         8     189ns     141ns     402ns  cuDeviceGet
```

However, I do not want to assess the maximum bandwidth, but instead monitoring the current bandwidth, as this [benchmark](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/graphics-performance-myths-debunked,3739-4.html#4) displays:

[image]

The same benchmark notes that:

> Myth: Graphics memory bandwidth utilization and PCIe bus utilization
>   are impossible to measure directly.
>  The amount of data moved between
>   graphics memory to the graphics processor and back is massive. That's
>   why graphics cards need such complex memory controllers capable of
>   pushing tons of bandwidth. In the case of AMD's Radeon R9 290X, you're
>   looking at up to 320GB/s. Nvidia's GeForce GTX 780 Ti is rated for up
>   to 336GB/s. Maximum PCIe throughput isn’t as impressive (15.75GB/s
>   through a 16-lane third-gen link), though it isn’t in as much demand.
>   But how much of that is utilized at any given point in time? Is this a
>   bottleneck? Until now, it has been hard to answer those questions. But
>   the Kepler architecture and NVAPI make it possible to address them
>   with more precision, we hope. EVGA GeForce GTX 690
>
> We began our exploration
>   looking at the BUS metric on a GeForce GTX 690. While Nvidia says it’s
>   unreliable, we still wondered what we could glean from our test
>   results. As we took readings, however, we faced another complication:
>   the card's two GK104 GPUs are not linked directly to the main PCIe
>   bus, but are rather switched through a PLX PEX 8747. So, no matter
>   what setting the motherboard uses, the GPUs always operate at PCI
>   Express 3.0 signaling rates, except when they're power-saving. That's
>   why GPU-Z shows them operating at PCIe 3.0, even on platforms limited
>   to PCIe 2.0. The PEX 8747 switch is what drops to previous-gen rates
>   on the host side.
>  With each GPU's bus controller operating at PCIe 3.0
>   on a 16-lane link, utilization at 100% should be 15.75GB/s. That
>   information alone doesn't help us much, though. It's impossible to say
>   how much traffic is directed at the host and how much goes to the
>   other GPU. And unfortunately, the PLX switch doesn't give us access to
>   more granular data. For now, we're left with a worst-case scenario:
>   that each GPU is receiving all of its traffic from the host, and none
>   is multicast.

They also note the following:

> Nvidia, through its GeForce driver, exposes a programming interface
>   ("NVAPI") that, among other things, allows for collecting performance
>   measurements. For the technically inclined, here is the relevant
>   section in the nvapi.h header file:
>
> > FUNCTION NAME: NvAPI_GPU_GetDynamicPstatesInfoEx
> >
> > DESCRIPTION: This API retrieves the NV_GPU_DYNAMIC_PSTATES_INFO_EX
> >     structure for the specified physical GPU. Each domain's info is
> >     indexed in the array. For example:
> >
> > - pDynamicPstatesInfo->utilization[NVAPI_GPU_UTILIZATION_DOMAIN_GPU] holds the info for the GPU domain. There are currently four domains
> >       for which GPU utilization and dynamic P-state thresholds can be
> >       retrieved: graphic engine (GPU), frame buffer (FB), video engine
> >       (VID), and bus interface (BUS).
>
> Beyond this header commentary, the API's specific functionality isn't
>   documented. The information below is our best interpretation of its
>   workings, though it relies on a lot of conjecture.
>
> - The graphics engine ("GPU") metric is expected to be your bottleneck in most games. If you don't see this at or close to 100%, something
>     else (like your CPU or memory subsystem) is limiting performance.
> - The frame buffer ("FB") metric is interesting, if it works as intended. From the name, you'd expect it to measure graphics memory
>     utilization (the percentage of memory used). That is not what this is,
>     though. It appears, rather, to be the memory controller's utilization
>     in percent. If that's correct, it would measure actual bandwidth being
>     used by the controller, which is not otherwise available as a
>     measurement any other way.
> - We're not as interested in the video engine ("VID"); it's not generally used in gaming, and registers a flat 0% typically. You'd
>     only see the dial move if you're encoding video through ShadowPlay or
>     streaming to a Shield.
> - **The bus interface ("BUS") metric refers to utilization of the PCIe controller**, again, as a percentage. The corresponding measurement,
>     which you can trace in EVGA PrecisionX and MSI Afterburner, is called
>     "GPU BUS Usage".
>
> We asked Nvidia to shed some light on the inner workings of NVAPI. Its
>   response confirmed that the FB metric measures graphics memory
>   bandwidth usage, but **Nvidia dismissed the BUS metric as "considered
>   to be unreliable and thus not used internally".**
>
> We asked AMD if it had any API or function that allowed for similar
>   measurements. After internal verification, company representatives
>   confirmed that they did not. As much as we would like to, we are
>   unable to conduct similar tests on AMD hardware.

I am okay if the PCI Express bus usage measurement is a bit noisy.

On Microsoft Windows, I use  [MSI Afterburner](https://gaming.msi.com/features/afterburner):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can be accomplished with the Intel Performance Counter Monitor (PCM) tools: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor.  As of v2.5 it supports PCIe monitoring on Xeon E5 processors.  ([ref](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/393529))  Looks like subsequent releases added support for more processor types: Haswell, Broadwell, Skylake.

Comment: Could you include a photo of this software in use?

Comment: Intel has discontinued support for PCM.  It's now on https://github.com/opcm/pcm